# Selebiun Crawler Timeout Issues C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following code I am running and during execution I receive an error.

```
  public void GetCategoriesSelenium() {
            string javascript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"GetCategory.js");
            CrawlerWebSeleniumJS.ExecuteScript("var finished;");
            CrawlerWebSeleniumJS.ExecuteScript("var all_categories;");
            CrawlerWebSeleniumJS.ExecuteScript("finished = false;");
            CrawlerWebSeleniumJS.ExecuteScript("all_categories = [];");

            CrawlerWebSelenium.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            CrawlerWebSelenium.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            CrawlerWebSelenium.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

            AddToConsole("CRAWLER: GET - Categories");

            try {
                CrawlerWebSeleniumJS.ExecuteScript(javascript);
                }
            catch {
                }

            int ready = 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < ready; i++) {
                try {
                    if (CrawlerWebSeleniumJS.ExecuteScript("return finished").ToString() == "True") {
                        i = i++ + ready++;
                        }
                    else {
                        ready++;
                        }
                    }
                catch {

                    }
                }
            AddToCatsTreeSelenium();
            }

$('.p-pstctgry-lnk-ctgry').each(function (i) {
    var idBits = this.id.split('_');
    var theId = idBits[1];
    var theTitle = this.text;
    var subcategories = [];
    //initiate ajax request for json results
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'URL REMOVED',
        data: {
            nodeType: 'cat',
            level1id: theId
        }
    }).done(function (theJSON1) {
        var thelength1 = Object.keys(theJSON1['items']).length;
        //loop through found subs
        for (var i = 0; i < thelength1; i++) {
            //start of next recursive block to copy and paste inside
            var subsubcategories = [];
            //initiate ajax request for sub json results
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'URL REMOVED',
                data: {
                    nodeType: 'cat',
                    level1id: theId,
                    level2id: theJSON1['items'][i]['id']
                }
            }).done(function (theJSON2) {
                var thelength2 = Object.keys(theJSON2['items']).length;
                for (var k = 0; k < thelength2; k++) {
                    //start of next recursive block to copy and paste inside
                    var subsubsubcategories = [];
                    //initiate ajax request for sub json results
                    if ((theJSON2['items'][k]['id'] != 'OFFER') && (theJSON2['items'][k]['id'] != 'WANTED')) {
                        $.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: 'URL REMOVED',
                            data: {
                                nodeType: 'cat',
                                level1id: theId,
                                level2id: theJSON1['items'][i]['id'],
                                level3id: theJSON2['items'][k]['id']
                            }
                        }).done(function (theJSON3) {
                            var thelength3 = Object.keys(theJSON3['items']).length;
                            for (var l = 0; l < thelength3; l++) {
                                console.log('---' + theJSON3['items'][l]['value'] + ' ' + theJSON3['items'][l]['id']);
                                //store this subsub
                                subsubsubcategories.push({
                                    title: theJSON3['items'][l]['value'],
                                    id: theJSON3['items'][l]['id'],
                                    sub: ''
                                });
                            }
                            //end done theJSON
                        });
                    }
                    //end of next recursive block to copy and paste inside
                    console.log('--' + theJSON2['items'][k]['value'] + ' ' + theJSON2['items'][k]['id']);
                    //store this subsub
                    subsubcategories.push({
                        title: theJSON2['items'][k]['value'],
                        id: theJSON2['items'][k]['id'],
                        sub: subsubsubcategories
                    });
                }
                //end done theJSON
            });
            console.log('-' + theJSON1['items'][i]['value'] + ' ' + theJSON1['items'][i]['id']);
            //store this sub with -> subsub
            subcategories.push({
                title: theJSON1['items'][i]['value'],
                id: theJSON1['items'][i]['id'],
                sub: subsubcategories
            });
            //end of next recursive block to copy and paste inside

            //end sub loop
        }
        console.log('' + theTitle + ' ' + theId);
        //store this cat with -> sub -> subsub
        all_categories.push({
            title: theTitle,
            id: theId,
            sub: subcategories
        });
        console.log(all_categories);
        //end first json subcat loop
    });
    //end main cat scan loop
});
finished = true;
```

The above code is the method that I run and the code that is under it is pure javascript that is being run through selenium.

So issue one, when the code is run selenium locks up. Which I can understand. This process takes about 4mins. After 60secs it times out with the error

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out after 60 seconds.

Which is really annoying and locks the system up. I know a really quick and easy way to get this fixed. (Thread.Sleep(300000) which is disgusting...

My thoughts are, maybe it is running a javascript query and waiting for it to finish and I am constantly pounding Selenium with more javascript requests which time out as expected.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver's constructor should have an overload that includes a `TimeSpan` indicating the timeout for the HTTP client used by the .NET bindings to communicate with the remote end. Setting that to an appropriately large value should be sufficient to let the operation complete.

Comment: Is that not what 
`codeCrawlerWebSelenium.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            CrawlerWebSelenium.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            CrawlerWebSelenium.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));`

doing?

Comment: No, not at all. None of those timeouts affect the HTTP communication between the language bindings and the so-called "remote end" of the driver implementation. The constructor overload is what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: Cheers man, ill have a bit of a dig into it and see what I can find